# zip file protection on server

Tags: php, zip, hosting

I have zip files in my website and I made a log in system so only users with valid passwords can download the zip files **ONCE**.

But there is always a possibility that they can download the zip files directly by entering the file path in the browser address bar.

You can get the link of the zip file by viewing the source code.

How can I deny people from downloading zip files by simply posting the file link in the browser address bar? is possible?

Comment: Don't store it in an accessible location, and serve it through PHP instead.

Comment: Thanks for comment. anywhere I will store them it will be shown in source code

Comment: I don't think you fully understand what I mean, I'll write it up fuller and post it as an answer, one moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of placing the file in a web accessible folder (`/var/www/` for example), place it above it so users can't browse to it (like `/var/files`). Then to serve it to your users, after they type the password, with a php script, have the script set the headers as they would if it were a file, and use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to output the contents of the file to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a folder in your root (~/) called secure_zip or something. This should sit alongside your public_html folder (meaning they cannot be accessed by typing in a URL).

Next, create a new php script, called file.php or something:-

```
<?php
public function sendFile() {
    $filename            = "sample.zip";
    $attachment_location = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
        . "../secure_zip/" . $filename;

    if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {
        header('Cache-Control: public'); // needed for i.e.
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
        readfile($attachment_location);
        die();
    } else {
        die('Error: File not found.');
    }
}
```

And call sendFile() if you authenticate the user using whatever logic you like, eg:

```
if (true) { sendFile(); }
```

Comment: Why "application/pdf"? Is that a typo?